# How to add objects to array at specific index in async completion block using Swift

Tags: ios, parsing, swift, block

Having trouble with the concurrency of this, ultimately I'm trying to add async fetched objects  to an array, in the order in which the request was made, i.e. first fetch should add to array[0], second fetch should add to array[1], etc. The problem is, by the time the fetch completes, my index count has already changed, how can I pass the index count to the async block, so it uses the right one?

```
class BATableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var paymentArray = [[AnyObject]]()
    var keepCount = 0


func buildPaymentsArray(expenses: Array<AnyObject>!){
    for (index, expense) in enumerate(expenses) {
        // query for all Payments for that expense
        var paymentQuery = PFQuery(className: "Payment")
        paymentQuery.whereKey("expense", equalTo: expense)
        paymentQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            self.paymentArray[self.keepCount] = objects
            self.keepCount++
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pre-extend your array, and insert them where you want them:

```
func buildPaymentsArray(expenses: Array<AnyObject>!){
    // Pre-allocate your array. (This *really* shouldn't be AnyObject if you can at all help it)
    self.paymentArray = [[AnyObject]](count: expenses.count repeatedValue: []) 

    for (index, expense) in enumerate(expenses) {
        // query for all Payments for that expense
        var paymentQuery = PFQuery(className: "Payment")
        paymentQuery.whereKey("expense", equalTo: expense)
        paymentQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            self.paymentArray[index] = objects  // <=== write it to the index location from expenses
            self.keepCount++ // <== I assume you shouldn't need this
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Parse returns & sets up their fetch with AnyObject but I agree I would like to have something more typed. This worked wonderfully, I swear I tried using index before